# Use name of table as input in procedure and store the output of SELECT statement in output variable SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a procedure, that will accept as input a variable called `@tablename` and will return as output the value of a variable called `@myoutput`. As the names of the variables signify, `@tablename` should be the name of a table and `@myoutput` should be just be the sum of the the first column of the table specified  by `@tablename`, divided by the number 3.3. The procedure I have written is the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sample_proc
@tablename VARCHAR(MAX),
@myoutput DECIMAL(20,5) OUTPUT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    @myoutput=EXEC('SELECT SUM('+@tablename+'.column1)/3.3)'
```

When I just use `EXEC()`, the select statement is executed as it should, but I cannot get the value I want from the table. What I want, is to store the value I calculate in the variable `@myoutput`, and export that to my main script. The above code produces an error. Does anyone know how I can implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you're not using a valid syntax due your SELECT command has no FROM clause.

Then you should use [sp_executesql](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx) just to take care of the output parameters.

> ```
> create table xx (id int, column1 int);
> create table yy (id int, column1 int);
> insert into xx values (1, 1),(2,2),(3,3);
> insert into yy values (1,10),(3,30),(4,40);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE sample_proc
> (
>     @tablename VARCHAR(MAX),
>     @myoutput DECIMAL(20,5) OUTPUT
> )
> AS
>     SET NOCOUNT ON;
>
>     DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
>     DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);
>
>     SET @ParmDefinition = '@Total decimal(20,5) OUTPUT';
>     SET @Cmd = 'SELECT @Total = (SUM(column1)/3.3) FROM [' + @tablename + ']';
>
>     -- just to show SQL command.
>     SELECT @Cmd;
>
>     EXEC sp_executesql @Cmd, @ParmDefinition, @Total = @myoutput out;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @op DECIMAL(20,5);
> EXEC sample_proc 'xx', @op OUT
> SELECT @op;
> EXEC sample_proc 'yy', @op OUT
> SELECT @op;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                             |
> | :------------------------------------------- |
> | SELECT @Total = (SUM(column1)/3.3) FROM [xx] |
>
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 1.81818          |
>
> | (No column name)                             |
> | :------------------------------------------- |
> | SELECT @Total = (SUM(column1)/3.3) FROM [yy] |
>
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 24.24242         |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f707284d45143f16e1e36085c7cd5cab)*

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sp_executesql` to get `output` parameter from `dynamic sql`:

```
alter PROCEDURE dbo.sample_proc
    @tablename sysname,
    @myoutput DECIMAL(20,5) OUTPUT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'select @myoutput = SUM(column1)/3.3 from ' + @tablename;
    declare @params nvarchar(100) = N'@myoutput DECIMAL(20,5) output';
    exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,  @myoutput= @myoutput output;
go
```